# Include condition in TYPO3 repository query

Tags: typo3

I have this query in my repository:

```
public function fetchAccountRecord(int $guideOption, string $fact, int $adapter = NULL) {

    $query = $this->createQuery();
    $query->getQuerySettings()->setIgnoreEnableFields(TRUE);
    $query->getQuerySettings()->setEnableFieldsToBeIgnored(['starttime','endtime']);
    $query->matching(
        $query->logicalAnd(
            [
                $query->equals('guide_option', $guideOption),
                $query->equals('fact', $fact)
            ]
        )
    );

    return $query;
}
```

How can I include an additional constraint for `$adapter` if it exists? So I've tried adding

```
$adapter ? $query->equals('adapter', $adapter) : NULL
```

but doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of the fact that `QueryInterface::logicalAnd()` also accepts an array of constraints. Then you conditionally extend that array:

```php
$query = $this->createQuery();
$query->getQuerySettings()->setIgnoreEnableFields(TRUE);
$query->getQuerySettings()->setEnableFieldsToBeIgnored(['starttime','endtime']);

$constraints = [
    $query->equals('guide_option', $guideOption),
    $query->equals('fact', $fact),
];

if ($adapter) {
    $constraints[] = $query->equals('adapter', $adapter);
}

$query->matching($query->logicalAnd($constraints));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
$constrains= [];
$constrains[] =  $query->equals('guide_option', $guideOption);
$constrains[] =  $query->equals('fact', $fact);

if($adapter) {
   $constrains[] =  $query->equals('adapter', $adapter);
}

$query->matching($query->logicalAnd($constrains);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to do something like that:

```
public function fetchAccountRecord(int $guideOption, string $fact, int $adapter = NULL) {

$query = $this->createQuery();
$query->getQuerySettings()->setIgnoreEnableFields(TRUE);
$query->getQuerySettings()->setEnableFieldsToBeIgnored(['starttime','endtime']);

$constraints[]

if($adapter) {
   $constraints[] = $query->equals('adapter', $adapter);
}

 $constraints[] =  $query->logicalAnd(
        $query->equals('guide_option', $guideOption),
        $query->equals('fact', $fact),
   );

$query->matching($query->logicalAnd($constraints));

return $query;
```

}